# how to groupby specific dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    name    style val1 val2 val3
23  sher      D     2    5    6
56  sher      C     3    2    4
34  David     A     1    1    1
47  iamgo     B     4    4    3
77  para      A     6    4    2
120 moli      A     7    2    5
86  para      A     5    4    1
```

I want to create new dataframe using groupby "name" that will return the following:

```
          style val1 val2 val3
  name
  sher      D,C   3    5    4
  David     A     1    1    1
  iamgo     B     4    4    3
  para      A     6    4    2
  moli      A     7    2    5
```

for "style" I want to add the value in case its not the same value (like with "para"),
for "val1" and "val2" the maximum value,
for "val3" the minimum value,
and reset the indexes.
here's my code:

```
df.groupby('name').agg({
    'style': sum,
    'val1': max,
    'val2': max,
    'val3': min
    })
```

output:

```
          style val1 val2 val3
  name
  sher      DC   3    5    4
  David     A    1    1    1
  iamgo     B    4    4    3
  para      AA   6    4    2
  moli      A    7    2    5
```

what I missing here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` function instead `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('name').agg({
      'style': ','.join,
      'val1': max,
      'val2': max,
      'val3': min
})

print (df1)
      style  val1  val2  val3
name                         
David     A     1     1     1
iamgo     B     4     4     3
moli      A     7     2     5
para    A,A     6     4     1
sher    D,C     3     5     4
```

If need unique values convert values to sets:

```
df2 = df.groupby('name').agg({
      'style': lambda x: ','.join(set(x)),
      'val1': max,
      'val2': max,
      'val3': min
})

print (df2)
      style  val1  val2  val3
name                         
David     A     1     1     1
iamgo     B     4     4     3
moli      A     7     2     5
para      A     6     4     1
sher    D,C     3     5     4
```

Comment: Thanks! and how i can add another column that calls "appearance"  and count the appearance of "name"?

Comment: @danan - Do you think `df1 = df.groupby('name').agg({
      'style': ','.join,
      'val1': max,
      'val2': max,
      'val3': min,
      'name':'size'
}).rename(columns={'name':'appearance'})
` ?

Comment: @jezreal, its working! thanks again. could you please explain how? why 'name': 'size' return the count of 'name'? does 'size' is a function?

Comment: @danan - yes, it is function - [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) like `min`, `max` are functions too.

Comment: I was confused because the ' ' sign

Comment: @danan - yop, if use `max` it is python function `max`, if use `'max'` it is opandas fucntion max [`GroupBy.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html)